# Relay controlled by Arduino via HC12 to a raspberry pi

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to implement a wireless soil moisture sensor using a HC12 connected to a Arduino, to send the signal (values: 0-100%) to then activate the a relay connected to a raspberry pi 3, depending on a specific percentage (ex: 20% on, 90% off). I figured out how to send the values and I am able to see them on the  pi, but I cannot activate the relay. Please Help.

This is the code I am using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import smtplib 
import time
from time import sleep 
import serial

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Set our GPIO numbering to BCM
relay_pin = 16
GPIO.setup(relay_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay_pin, 1) 

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0",9600)   #Open port with baud rate

try:
    while True:
        received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
        data_left = ser.inWaiting()             
        received_data += ser.read(data_left)
        print (received_data)                   #print received data
        ser.write(received_data)                #transmit data serially

        if received_data <= '20':
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, 0)
        elif received_data >= '90':
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, 1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: can you share the code that you tried?

Comment: yes, I just posted it on my question.

Comment: How are you distinguishing `100` from being three numbers 1,0,0 or a single number 100 or maybe 10 and 0? How are you making sure you get the full number and not just the first digit?

Comment: I do not know how to distinguish a number such as '100' % since I am not too familiar with coding. Therefore, I am not sure if it is possible to make a relay work based on analog data sent from the Arduino, is it possible to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is in statement `if`.

```
if received_data <= '20':
    GPIO.output(relay_pin, 0)
elif received_data >= '90':
    GPIO.output(relay_pin, 1)
```

`'20'` is a string not number.
Try to remove quotes, like below:

```
if received_data <= 20:
    GPIO.output(relay_pin, 0)
elif received_data >= 90:
    GPIO.output(relay_pin, 1)
```

Comment: `received_data` is also a string.

Comment: I removed the quotes, but still the relay is not responding, yet I am able to see the data from the arduino.

Comment: So try convert `received_data` to `int` and then make comparison. `if int(received_data) <= 20`

Answer (score 0):

I am still having trouble with the code, and once I changed the code to: if int(received_data) <= 20, an error message appears. This is the modified code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import smtplib 
import time
from time import sleep 
import serial

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Set our GPIO numbering to BCM
relay_pin = 16
GPIO.setup(relay_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.HIGH) 

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0",9600)  

try:
    while True:
        received_data = ser.read()   #read serial port
        data_left = ser.inWaiting()             
        received_data += ser.read(data_left)
        print (received_data)     #print received data
        ser.write(received_data) #transmit data serially

        if int(received_data) <= 20:
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        elif int(received_data) >= 90:
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.LOW)
        else:
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.LOW)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

However, when I remove the "if int(received_data) <= 20", and leave the code as:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import smtplib 
import time
from time import sleep 
import serial

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Set our GPIO numbering to BCM
relay_pin = 16
GPIO.setup(relay_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.HIGH) 

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0",9600)  

try:
    while True:
        received_data = ser.read()   #read serial port
        data_left = ser.inWaiting()             
        received_data += ser.read(data_left)
        print (received_data)     #print received data
        ser.write(received_data) #transmit data serially

        if received_data <= 20:
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        elif received_data >= 90:
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.LOW)
        else:
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.LOW)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The relay turns on, but it does not respond to the serial data received from Arduino and the soil moisture sensor. I was thinking of maybe define the serial data from Arduino to lets say: turn the relay on at 20% of humidity and turn off when the soil moisture is at 90%, and therefore define the 20% value as "1" or as a GPIO.HIGH to turn the relay on, or vice versa, but I do not know how to achieve that. Any advice?

Comment: or another idea: by using either node red or other application to allow the user to choose a specific soil moisture level from an Android app.